# Eclipse Java Profiler prematurely exiting without results

Tags: java, eclipse, profiler

I've installed the Java Profiler for Eclipse Keplar as per [these instructions](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/installguide/InstallGuide30.html) (For windows). I then applied [these instructions](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html) to start profiling my Java application.

I opened a command prompt and ran RAServer.exe which I left running. I then set the profiling configuration to that of a Java application, and selected my class with the "main" function for the profiler to execute. (A JFrame).

However when I execute the profiling by going to `Run > Profile` in the Eclipse IDE, nothing happens, besides a quick flicker of a progress bar in the IDE status bar. Nothing appears in the "Profiling Monitor" window tab.

What am I doing wrong? (How can I find out what's going wrong?) Thanks

Comment: These instructions are for 10 year old code. Eclipse Hyades was replaced with TPTP long ago. Eclipse TPTP is also no [longer supported](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/)

Comment: As an alternative, take a look at Yourkit (http://www.yourkit.com/) which has decent Eclipse integration.